# bash script mostrar información de procesos

Tags: linux, bash, script, línea-de-comandos

estoy haciendo un script que cuando intento ejecutar me salen dos errores en el programa principal que no entiendo:

```
main_program(){

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>$TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>$TITLE</h1>
   <p>$TIME_STAMP</p>
  $(show_processes_info)


</body>
</html>
_EOF_

}
```

me sale el siguiente error:

```
línea 43: error sintáctico cerca del elemento inesperado `newline'
línea 43: `<html>'
```

Refiriéndose a `<html>`
Se colorea `head`, y no debería estar coloreado

Se agradece ayuda

Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 43? ¿Cómo ejecutas el script? ¿Cuál es el objetivo de este? ¿Qué relación tiene con [tu anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/118580/83) que tenía un error y del que no diste mayor respuesta? Sin estos detalles no podemos ayudarte. Eso sí, siempre es recomendable pegar el script en https://www.shellcheck.net/ para tener un primer análisis de errores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas metiendo codigo HTML en un script de Bash. Es normal que no entienda las etiquetas . Tienes que ver los script en Bash como una secuencia de ordenes en la terminal.

Supongo que lo que pretendes es generar una pagina "html" con los resultados de tu funcion "show_processes_info". Para que te la genere como quieres debes meter todo el codigo HTML en un echo:

```
main_program(){

echo "
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>$TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>$TITLE</h1>
    <p>$TIME_STAMP</p>
    $(show_processes_info)


</body>
</html>
"
}
```

Esto imprimirá por pantalla esa pagina web resultante. Si la quieres en un fichero puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
./script.sh > fichero_salida.html
```

y listo!

Answer (score 2):

Al principio me quedé con la respuesta de @a-villegas pero, leyendo el código que pusiste, noté que pegaste algo como `_EOF_`, lo que me hizo pensar que pegaste ese código mal a tu script.

Primero, lo que te indica ese error es el caracter ">" del texto `<html>` que pegaste en tu script, ese caracter sirve para redireccionar algún descriptor de archivo a algún otro lugar, pero como le diste "Enter", es decir, le diste un salto de línea "\n", entonces te muestra ese error que sería un "Oye, yo `>` esperaba un archivo o descriptor de archivo, y no un salto de línea". Pero bueno, @a-villegas da a entender que lo tienes que pasar como texto.

De acuerdo con todo salvo la expresión `_EOF_` que pegaste hasta abajo de tu código. Yo suelo ver y usar ese tipo de expresiones cuando uso un [here document](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) y, en resumen, este bloque de código tiene propósitos especiales y sería algo así:

```
$comando_a_ejecutar << _indicador_de_final_
bla bla
foo baz bar
todo esto es vil texto que no se interpretará en la consola (a excepción de las expansiones)
hasta que encuentre "_indicador_de_final_" al inicio
y luego le pasará este bloque de código al stdin del comando_a_ejecutar
_indicador_de_final_
```

Entonces, ese  `_EOF_` es ese indicador de final del bloque, por lo que, tratando de reconstruir el fragmento del script en el que te basaste, quedaría algo así.

```
main_program() {

    cat - << _EOF_
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>$TITLE</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>$TITLE</h1>
   <p>$TIME_STAMP</p>
  $(show_processes_info)


</body>
</html>
_EOF_

}
```

Y, pensando en que `show_processes_info` es una función que no falla, todo se muestra de acuerdo al formato que querías dar.

Lo que hace este código es decirle a `cat` que lea del stdin y que lo trate como un archivo, el stdin es el here document, y luego `cat` lo muestra en la terminal (su stdout).